# Change formula values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've an excel file with a lot of formulas that referenced an old sheet.

I've deleted it and now the forumla went from:

`sumifs(RawData!$A:A)`

to:

`sumifs(!"Ref#!$A:A)`

How to change to replace `!Ref#` with "NewSheet" in all cell?

Common Search and Replace didn't do it!

Comment: No repo.  Search and replace works for me

Comment: Yeah,... worked on me home pc, with Excel 2019.... the other computer had 2016... i'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: Don't forget to pay attention to whether you're searching values or formulas

Answer (score 0):

just do a find and replace > select the range of affected area
CTRL+F > ALT+P
find what: #REF
Replace with : NewSheet

Comment: Or `ctrl+H` to get to the find/replace at once

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you, using a screenshot, how I did it. Be aware that I just search on `REF!` (or `REF!A`, just to be sure how it works):

[image]

There is one important difference between my case and yours:
On my Excel sheet, I see `#REF!` while you mention `REF#!` (mind the position of the `#` character).

Are you sure you're not simply dealing with a typo?